# Proving a sequence is convergent and calculating its limit

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, convergence-divergence, proof-verification

In my assignment I have to solve the following question. I think I have an idea how to solve it, but I suspect there is a little thing in my solution which is wrong. If you can tell if my solution is correct or not, it will be great.

**Here is the question:**

Let $a_{n}$ be sequence which in it, $0<a_{1}<6$, and is a "recursive sequence": $a_{n+1}=\sqrt{6a_{n}}$.

Prove that $(a_{n})$ is convergent and calculate its limit.

**My solution:**

1) Prove that $(a_{n})>0$ for all n, by induction.

2) Prove that $(a_{n})\leq6$ for all n, by induction.

After these two steps I can say that the sequence is bounded. If I prove now it is increasing, I can say its convergent.

3) Prove that the sequence is increasing, with the following:

- Assume that the sequence is not increasing, so $\sqrt{6a_{n}}-a_{n} \leq 0$
- $\sqrt{6a_{n}} \leq a_{n}$
- $\sqrt{6}\sqrt{a_{n}}\leq a_{n}$
- Now use $a_{n-1}$ to demonstrate the contradiction. That's the thing I'm worried about:
- $\sqrt{6}\sqrt{6a_{n-1}}\leq \sqrt{6a_{n-1}}$
- $36\sqrt{a_{n-1}}\leq \sqrt{6}\sqrt{a_{n-1}}$
- Now divide by $\sqrt{6a_{n-1}}$ which I proved to be greater than $0$, and:
- $36 \leq \sqrt{6}$ which is a contradiction.
- Therefore, the sequence is increasing and convergent.

Calculating its limit is easy enough.

Is my solution correct?

Thank you.

Comment: Your solution is incorrect. Actually $\sqrt{a_n}=\sqrt{\sqrt{6a_{n-1}}}$. And then there are some other wrong computations in the following, but this is not important.

Comment: @Crostul and what if I do something like this: $(\sqrt{6a_{n}})^2 \leq (a_{n})^2$? Then I get that ${6a_n} \leq (a_{n})^2$ and then divide by which is a contradiction to the boundery.

Comment: This is equivalent on the solution I gave in my answer below, so: yes, it works.

Comment: @Crostul thank you! tried not to look at it.

Comment: @Crostul can I do that:  $\frac{(a_{n})^2}{a_{n}}$?

Comment: Yes, you can do it: why not?

Comment: Thank you, just wasn't sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct solution is much easier than yours:
$$a_{n+1}=\sqrt{6}\sqrt{a_n} > \sqrt{a_n}\sqrt{a_n} = a_n$$
since you already proved that $0 < a_n <6$, so $\sqrt{a_n}<\sqrt{6}$.